# Is JasperManager class deprecated?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is ***JasperManager*** class deprecated?

I've included the *jasperreports-5.0.0.jar* in my eclipse Java project, but I can't find this class and I've this compile error: `JasperManager cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, the substitute and more specific class is:

```
JRXmlLoader
```

Source: [JasperManager](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperManager.html)